# Email Sending via SPD Workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email

I created one workflow to send email via SPD. The workflow sends the email to the person whose Work e-mail appear in userdisp.aspx page only. This page is accessible via Site Actions > Site Permissions > Click on any user account.

[image]

The page above displays user information including Work e-mail. If the Work e-mail field is empty then email is not send to the user because I am using the user account name in "TO" field in email action of SPD workflow. How can I get Work e-mail for every user in SharePoint? Please note I have updated all user account's email property in AD services. But strange only this user "nkassem" Work e-mail appears and only this user receives email.

How can I get Work e-mail for all users in SharePoint?

Comment: These are coming from the user profiles. I'd assume that the user profile for only this user has work email listed. Have you synced user profiles with AD?

Comment: Yes I have full synced my user profile but still no change.